# How to Shorten Formula IF with too many conditions?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to create a formula for my Aging in Accounts Receivable - Tuition Fees [See Table 2: Accounts Receivable Schedule].

Every month, a student must achieve a certain balance or else, its excess will fall over due [See Table 1: Student Tuition Fee Balance Matrix].

So there are three conditions, the month we are currently in, the school level of the student and if his balance to date is greater than the matrix [over due] or less [no over due balance].

**The Formula**

```
=IF(B8<N9,IF(B8<M9,IF(B8<L9,IF(B8<K9,IF(B8<J9,IF(B8<I9,IF(B8<H9,IF(B8<G9,IF(B8<F9,IF(B8<E9,0,"FALSE"),E10),F10),G10),H10),I10),J10),K10),L10),M10)
```

[image: Table 1]

[image: Accounts Receivable Schedule]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking two questions based on the details of your question. The first part is pretty clear from your title 'How to Shorten Formula IF with too many conditions?' and the image provided from Table 1.

The second part I do not understand what you are trying to achieve.

To simply answer your first question as per your title, the easiest way to shorten the `IF` formula is to use a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions to search the table for the value of the given month in Cell **B8**.

```
=INDEX(E9:N10,2,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(B8),MONTH(B8),DAY(1)),E9:N9,0))
```